# How to verify file Integrity?

Tags: linux, gnupg

I have downloaded a software(zipped), from a website: `example-linux.gtk.x86_64.zip`

There is another file given for verification, `example-linux.gtk.x86_64.zip.asc`, whose content are

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

Version: GnuPG v1

iQEcBAABAgAGBQJUPdCNAAoJEELXCMAlIIx7wV4IAI0GwTHy2biP4vp8E+YnYV4u
erog2kGvyU99bJud8CKfgBCKXSn9KdZovo4vCbOoyiVJ/iC8EHqNiK8J9IOMcbGz
hEcHnWE7LWaJPGnFokSh/UhSszDXIRyBUrq2pLg71cME1RYU/2U85ctHxnzFOziD
L3+rPzeFhJ14MpSWTiFh0fUxf299BzUUJBaKFllNmNHkWS4C/SFKmnmG+U8EIB1P
m/Fk6LP/C5X5OFB/XTmsRZRkMbhrMfn6ykfdNL/ltjynUIaoNJYZm5KJeWlvjyxf
XoBRGHslB4H+yv7Mf0qG9PPNWvBUan65t8YtEqyYlrGgTAzo/Umfkvswuv88TE0=
=yhw9

-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

I'm using linux machine and I want to know How can I check the integrity of ***.zip*** file using ***.zip.asc*** file ?

Comment: Usually sites provide instructions for this. Where did you download these files? Also, the `.asc` file is less about integrity but about verifying who has provided these files. To check the signature you have to know the signers (public) key.

Comment: https://subgraph.com/vega/download/        click on download to see more links

Comment: See https://github.com/subgraph/Vega/wiki/Getting-Vega for instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general and as explained in [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/896228/how-to-verify-a-file-using-an-asc-signature-file), you need to

1. add the software vendor's public key to your keychain
2. get the signature (`*.asc`)
3. verify the signature via `gpg --verify $THE_SIGNATURE_ASC $THE_FILE`

Exact details and commands are in the answer linked above and in the [link provided by @Steffen-Ullrich](https://github.com/subgraph/Vega/wiki/Getting-Vega#signature-verification) in your exact case.